# Count how many columns have a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    x1    x2    x3    x4
1     20    30    0     0
2     60    0     0     0
3     10    30    0     0
4     30    30    30    30
```

I want to be able to query this and return the ID with the number of columns that have more than 0 as their value in that row. So the result would look like this:

```
ID    Count
1     2
2     1
3     2
4     4
```

Comment: will you always have columns x1,x2,x3,x4?

Comment: Yes, I will always have these columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, z.cnt
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
             FROM (VALUES (x1), (x2), (x3), (x4)) x(y)
             WHERE x.y > 0) z
```

This query makes use of a [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to create an in-line table whose *rows* are the *columns* of the initial table. Performing a `COUNT` on this in-line table, you can get the number of columns greater than zero.

I think this scales well if you have more than 4 columns.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b646/1)

Comment: This is a neat solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Select 
    ID,
    Case When x1 <> 0 Then 1 Else 0 End + 
    Case When x2 <> 0 Then 1 Else 0 End + 
    Case When x3 <> 0 Then 1 Else 0 End + 
    Case When x4 <> 0 Then 1 Else 0 End as Count
From MyTable
```

While this is easy to code, the more columns you have, the larger your select is going to be the more columns you will have to add.

Comment: Is there a way around having to code all of the column names? Or is this just SQL by design that I have to write out all specific column names? Like write a range of columns instead?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need if you have a fixed set of columns known at design time :

```
 SELECT ID,
        IIF (x1 > 0, 1, 0) + 
        IIF (x2 > 0, 1, 0) + 
        IIF (x3 > 0, 1, 0) + 
        IIF (x4 > 0, 1, 0) 
 FROM MyTable
```